# C# TabControl.SelectedIndex changes value unexpectedly

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a method called `OpenURL()` and `recordHistory()` with the following definitions:

```
public string OpenURL(string url)
{
       //get index of current tab
       int tabIndex = BrowserWindow.TabControlE.SelectedIndex;
       //create instance of History class
       History H = new History();
       //call recordHistory() method to record the url and tabIndex
       H.recordHistory(url, tabIndex);
}

public void recordHistory(string url, int tabIndex)
{
       //print the tabIndex
       Console.WriteLine("Tab is: "+tabIndex);
}
```

The scenario is: I would like to record history for each tab.
However, I am facing some unexpected behavior from `TabControl.SelectedIndex`.

When the first tab is created, the output in `recordHistory()` is:

```
Tab is: -1
```

When I refresh the page (call `OpenURL()` on the same tab), this time the output in `recordHistory()` is:

```
Tab is: 0
```

It seems that the first time a tab is created the `TabControl.SelectedIndex` value is wrong. This goes away after refreshing the page. How do I correct this so that it displays the correct value?

EDIT: Adding the `recordHistory()` call.

In class `BrowserWindow`:

```
private void BrowserWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabControl1 = new TabControl();
    TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    Tab Tab1 = new Tab(tab_counter, getHomePageURL());
    TabControl1.Controls.Add(Tab1.createNewTab());
    this.Controls.Add(TabControl1);
}
```

In class `Tab`:

```
class Tab
{
    int tab_ID;
    String tab_URL;
    TabPage page;

    public Tab(int tab_ID, String tab_URL)
    {
        this.tab_ID = tab_ID;
        this.tab_URL = tab_URL;
    }

    public TabPage createNewTab()
    {
        //Create a new tab
        page = new TabPage("New Tab");
        page.Text = this.tab_URLE;
        page.Controls.Add(R1);
        R1.Text = OpenURL(this.tab_URLE);
        return page;
    }

 }
```

The flow goes: `BrowserWindow_Load() --> createNewTab() --> OpenURL() --> recordHistory()`

Comment: You should post your code that calls your methods. It seems that you are calling `recordHistory` before initializing TabControl

Comment: I support @saidfagan. You should wait for the tab to initialize before checking on the index. There could be many possible solutions like you can have another property which can tell you if the tab is initialized. And if so, only then you add to history. And if not, wait for it by adding an awaited task.

Comment: @saidfagan Added the code!

Comment: It is no doubt a simple order-of-events problem.  Your "create tab" code runs before the TabControl gets added to the form.  So there simply is no selected index yet, thus -1.  Always best to separate the data from the view, add an "index" property to the Tab class.

Comment: @HansPassant So you recommend that I use the `tab_ID` field as a primary key to identify each tab?

Comment: I suppose I do, "id" is a bit too nondescript to be sure.  Do think about what needs to happen when you delete tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `BrowserWindow_Load` event. Change the order of the last 2 statements and it should work. Like this:

```
private void BrowserWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabControl1 = new TabControl();
    TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    Tab Tab1 = new Tab(tab_counter, getHomePageURL());
    this.Controls.Add(TabControl1);
    TabControl1.Controls.Add(Tab1.createNewTab());
}
```

Comment: It gives me the same output as before. I understand what you are trying to do though.